# clipPath cut off by container

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

So I am pretty close to my desired effect, the issue though is that the clipPath I am using while rotating gets cut off by the container. Is there a way to remedy this? I tried messing with the viewBox and other properties but to no avail. I am not super well versed in using clipPath. Would using CSS clip-path be a better call and just rotate a pseudo element the opposite way?

```css
.red {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/u8wSHMmMMXzZuAFBCmcsCK-650-80.jpg');
  background-size: 90%;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 700px;
  clip-path: url(#clipPolygon);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: 120px;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

svg {
}

defs {
  transition: all 5s;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <svg>
   <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipPolygon">
      <polygon points="200 250,400 100,300 50,0 0">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="2.5s" type="rotate" from="360 160 160" to="0 160 160" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </polygon>
    </clipPath>
   </defs>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="bg">
  <img src="https://www.mcgilvraydesign.com/img/bgdemo3.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your polygon as a CSS mask then you can easily handle the rotation using two elements rotating in opposite direction

```css
.red {
  background:url(https://www.mcgilvraydesign.com/img/bgdemo3.jpg) center/contain no-repeat;
  min-height:350px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.red > div {
  /* control the mask here */
  -webkit-mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0 400 300"><polygon points="200 250,400 100,300 50,0 0"/></svg>') 
               center/ /* position */
               300px 200px /* size */
               no-repeat;
          mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0 400 300"><polygon points="200 250,400 100,300 50,0 0"/></svg>') 
               center/
               300px 200px 
               no-repeat;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  animation:rotate 2s linear infinite;
}
.red > div::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  /*big values here to avoid the cut effet*/
  top:-100%;
  left:-100%;
  right:-100%;
  bottom:-100%;
  /* */
  /* Control the skull here */
  background: url('https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/u8wSHMmMMXzZuAFBCmcsCK-650-80.jpg') 
     50% 45%/ /* position */
     22% auto /* size*/
     no-repeat,
     #fff;
  animation:inherit;
  animation-direction:reverse;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    transform:rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
 <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: AH PERFECT! This makes things way easier! I had a version of this but was still wonky. Thanks a ton! Curious is the image in reverse actually moving? Or does it not move? I am just trying to envision how the reverse works. As mentally I think the skull would be going clockwise.

Comment: @OMGDrAcula simply imagine yourself moving inside a container that is also moving in the other direction. *you* will be moving but someone from the outside will see you not moving because the container will cancel your movement

Comment: that makes sense! Thanks a ton! I got so close last night until I saw the edges getting cut off.